# rails server (4.0.0) cannot start - Error: LoadError:8 lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require': libmysqlclient.so.18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I cannot start my rails server. The error shows:

```
$ rails server
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2a.rb:8:in `require': libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/marslo/Study/Codes/Ruby/RailsBegin/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

BUT! **mysql2.so can be fuond !!!**:

```
 $ ls -al /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 131K Oct  7 00:31 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
```

---

I'v installed the mysql **from source code**. And it was installed at:

```
$ whereis mysql
mysql: /usr/local/mysql
```

I tried install **mysql2** by gem with `--with-mysql-config`, everything just works fine:

```
$ sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.13
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.13...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.13...
```

---

Here my **database.yml**:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: RailsBegin_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: passwd
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Here my databases:

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+------------------------+
| Database               |
+------------------------+
| information_schema     |
| RailsBegin_development |
| mysql                  |
| performance_schema     |
| test                   |
+------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here my **bundle install**:

```
$ bundle install
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.8.1) 
Using atomic (1.1.14) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.25) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (2.0.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.0) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using jbuilder (1.5.1) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.13) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.10.0) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0) 
Using rails (4.0.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using sass (3.2.12) 
Using sass-rails (4.0.0) 
Using sdoc (0.3.20) 
Using turbolinks (1.3.0) 
Using uglifier (2.2.1) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

I don't know what's wrong with it. Is everyone can help me? Thanks in advance!!

============

## Update 1

I've uninstalled the mysql2 and reinstalled as **0.3.11**:

```
$ sudo gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.11 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-bin=/usr/local/mysql/bin
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.11.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.3.11
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.3.11...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.3.11...
```

And update **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
```

And **bundle install** again, **but 0.3.13 still be installed!**:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.8.1) 
Using atomic (1.1.14) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.3) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.25) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (2.0.2) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.0) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using jbuilder (1.5.1) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Installing mysql2 (0.3.13) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.10.0) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0) 
Using rails (4.0.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using sass (3.2.12) 
Using sass-rails (4.0.0) 
Using sdoc (0.3.20) 
Using turbolinks (1.3.0) 
Using uglifier (2.2.1) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

here **gem list**:

```
$ gem list | grep mysql2
mysql2 (0.3.13, 0.3.11)
```

By the way, the owner of mysql (installed by source code) is **mysql**:

```
$ ls -al
total 160K
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql  18K Sep 10 15:38 COPYING
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql 2.5K Sep 10 15:38 README
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql  87K Sep 10 15:38 INSTALL-BINARY
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  1 23:51 docs/
drwxr-xr-x  3 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  1 23:51 include/
drwxr-xr-x  3 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  1 23:51 lib/
drwxr-xr-x 10 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  1 23:52 mysql-test/
drwxr-xr-x 28 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  1 23:52 share/
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  1 23:52 scripts/
drwxr-xr-x  4 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  1 23:52 sql-bench/
drwxr-xr-x  4 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  1 23:52 man/
drwxr-xr-x  3 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  1 23:52 support-files/
-rw-r--r--  1 mysql mysql  943 Oct  1 23:55 my.cnf
drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  1 23:57 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  6 mysql mysql 4.0K Oct  7 01:04 data/
```

However, the owner of ruby is **root**.

Is that because of the **permission problem**?

====================

## Update 2

Install mysql2 version: **0.3.11**, with **--platform=ruby**:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall mysql2
$ sudo gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.11 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-bin=/usr/local/mysql/bin
$ rm -rf Gemfile.lock
$ bundle install
```

**mysql variables** can be found by:

```
$ mysqladmin variables
```

And, install **NodeJS**:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

And, it will works!!

```
$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-10-07 21:08:06] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-10-07 21:08:06] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-06-27) [i686-linux]
[2013-10-07 21:08:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3676 port=3000
```

Do not forgot start mysql server:

```
$ sudo service mysql start
```

====================

## Update 3

NodeJS installation for CentOS:

```
$ sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
$ mkdir nodjs && cd $_
$ wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
--2013-10-12 16:01:53--  http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
Resolving nodejs.org... 165.225.133.150
Connecting to nodejs.org|165.225.133.150|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 13633041 (13M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: “node-latest.tar.gz”

100%[============================================================================>] 13,633,041   513K/s   in 36s

2013-10-12 16:02:31 (375 KB/s) - “node-latest.tar.gz” saved [13633041/13633041]
$ tar xzf node-latest.tar.gz
$ cd node-v0.10.20/
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

===================

## Note

- This is not related with permission problem
- Delete *Gemfile.lock* first before running **bundle install** if anything updated in **Gemfile**

Comment: Install `mysql2` as `marslo`, not `root`.

Comment: The lib of ruby has been installed at **/usr/local/lib/ruby/**. I cannot install gems by `marslo`. By the way, the owner of mysql is `mysql`

Comment: Here the error about install mysql2 without `sudo`: `$ gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-bin=/usr/local/mysql/bin
Fetching: mysql2-0.3.13.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1 directory.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to GemFile `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'` and try Bundling Again.

Comment: Just looked at his gemfile and he doesn't have the mysql2 gem in his bundle output explains why :p

Comment: Hi @David, I have mysql2: `Using mysql2 (0.3.13)`

Comment: I've update the Gemfile, but, mysql2 still be installed as **0.3.13**. Why's that?

Comment: Change the **gemfile.lock**

Comment: Or alternatively delete the `gemfile.lock` and do a bundle install again

Comment: i thought the gemfile.lock is just an output log, doesn't actually affect the gemfile.  Is that true?

Comment: Yes! It works, I re-install mysql2 by ` $ sudo gem install mysql2 -v 0.3.11 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib --with-mysql-bin=/usr/local/mysql/bin`, and I delete the **Gemfile.lock** file. The mysql2 error gone.

Comment: But, the new error is shown: `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in 'autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)`

Comment: Install NodeJS for Java RunTime.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem after a MySQL update. In the end the steps required to fix it were:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
bundle install
```

...at this point the updated mysql2 gem installed and rails was able to start without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

### My System :- Windows 7 64 bit, MySQL 5.6, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 4.0.4

Do the below steps to install mysql2 in rails -

1. download mysql-connector-c-6.1.3-win32.zip from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads
2. upzip to 'C:\mysql-connector'
3. gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector"'
4. copy 'libmysql.dll' from 'C:\mysql-connector\lib' to 'C:\Ruby193\bin' directory
5. add gem 'mysql2' in Genfile.
6. delete 'Genfile.lock'
7. bundle install
8. rails server.

Enjoy !!!